# Desserialização do json errado na data do objeto no servidor java

Tags: java, json, wildfly

Tenho um objeto Usuario e nele contem o atribute dataDeNascimento, eu passo  o objeto usuario para o servidor, a data eu forneço no seguindo formato 2017-12-31, mas o servidor muda para 2017-12-30, sempre decrementa um dia na data

servidor

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/")
public Response store(Usuario usuario) {
    try {
        if(dao(this).existeEmail(usuario.getEmail())) {
            return erro("Email já existe!");
        }

        dao(this).save(usuario);

        return responseOk(usuario);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        return erroInterno(e);
    }
}
```

Modelo do Usuario

```
@Entity
class Usuario {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataDeNascimento;
 }
```